# TextButton in different file not recognized as TextButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using GetX in a Flutter project.

Using a function like `Get.snackbar()` will allow me to show a SnackBar, in which I want to inlcude a button using `mainButton`. This button has to be of type `TextButton`. Because I am using this type of SnackBar in a lot of parts of my project, I would like to have `TextButton` to be called from another file.

I create a file like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnackbarTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const SnackbarTextButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent),
        splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I include it where I use my SnackBar, but I get the error: `The argument type 'SnackbarTextButton' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextButton?'`.

How can I tell my file that I am actually returning a TextButton? How can I change the type of the widget that I am building on another file to match in this case `TextButton`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you use this `SnackbarTextButton ()` ?

Comment: As a property for Get.snackbar, like so: `Get.snackbar(mainButton: SnackbarTextButton(text: 'My text'),);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a helper method instead of `StatelessWidget`, because if the required type is a `TextButton?` then using `StatelessWidget`, you should extend or implement the `TextButton` type:

```
class SnackbarTextButton extends TextButton {// ...}
```

But this will give you extra unnecessary work for your case because, you can simply make a helper method to return that `TextButton` widget you want:

```
TextButton snackbarTextButton ({required this.text}) {
 return TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent),
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(
    text,
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 12,
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
);
 }
```

then call it like this:

```
snackbarTextButton(text: "exampleText"), // this will be valid for TextButton type
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I am still not able to achieve this. Does this go in a separate file? Could you please explain a bit further? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Just as a comment, it should be just `({text})` without the `required`. That way it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will solve your error
This is how you should do it

for **main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Snackbar'),
    );
  }
}
```

you can use your **Get.showSnackbar** like this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title), actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.showSnackbar(const GetSnackBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                titleText: SnackbarTextButton(text: "SnackbarTextButton"),
                message: "Hello",
              ));
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Show snackBar",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
      ]),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[]),
    );
  }
}
```

your text button code

```
class SnackbarTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const SnackbarTextButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor:
              MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
          overlayColor:
              MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent),
          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Get.back();
        },
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is basically explaining how to use Snackbar, not really solving my problem...